# RadSideDrawer error in Angular 5 and nested routers

Tags: angular, mobile, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have worked from tns side drawer template. In my app, I need to login first then go to the main page where the user will access a "hamburger" menu with all options and functions.

From the template, I have created a "logado" module with a HTML from a root page where was inserted the RadSideDrawer basic structure. There, I put a router-outlet to show the pages and, into each page, I put the "hamburger" button to show the side drawer menu.

This worked fine from the template, but when I have moved the structure from / to the "logado" folder and I maded the changes needed to app works, I received this error:

> ERROR TypeError: sideDrawer.showDrawer is not a function

I don't know what I do because I've checked the imports on the HomeModule, AppModule and LogadoModule, but nothing solves this problem.
A little bit of code...
HomeComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as app from "application";
import { RadSideDrawer } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer";

@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
        // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Init your component properties here.
    }

    onDrawerButtonTap(): void {
        const sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>app.getRootView();
        sideDrawer.showDrawer();
    }
}
```

LogadoComponent:

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";
import { NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular";
import { LogadoRoutingModule } from "./logado-routing.module";
import { LogadoComponent } from "./logado.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule,
        LogadoRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        LogadoComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class LogadoModule { }
```

Full code at git: https://gitlab.com/gilvandev/teste-contabilidade.git

Comment: ideally you should be using a `@ViewChild()` instead of the nativescript way of using `app.getRootView()`

Comment: Could you tell me a bit more about this change? I really don't know how to use  @ViewChild instead of app.getRootView()

Comment: in vanilla nativescript, `app.getRootView()` is the correct way, but in nativescript with angular (or any angular apps) you should use `@ViewChild()`

Comment: Ok. I understand. But...how? I read some docs about `@ViewChild` but I don't know how to replace in the code. Could you help me?

Comment: have you attempted to change the code? or are you wanting it written for you?

Comment: I've tried but with a lot of errors. Do you have an example?